# Smaller number saying it is bigger than a bigger number (If Statement)

Tags: java, android, int, logic

Hello I have an if statement that checks to see if the tapped area is in within the boundaries of the device. At a high level this is what it is.

```
int width = <WidthOfDeviceInPixels>;
float x = <TappedXCoordinate>;
if(x > width)
{
    x = width - sizeOfBox;
}
```

My test cases show that no matter what x is, it will always hit this statement. Here are a couple of logs I printed

Width: 1440 | X: 220.213
Width: 1440 | X: 219.128
Width: 1440 | X: 243.832
Width: 1440 | X: 238.235

Could it be because I am comparing an integer to a float. To my knowledge I thought that the integer would be auto casted to a floating point type.

Comment: Just run it in a debugger and see what width and x really are just before execution of the if-statement. Or just print the values.

Comment: @FredK The values I put above are the printed values

Answer (score 0):

The actual code contained a long if statement referring to some specific components. There was a semi colon at the end of the if statement. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for the help. Kinda embarrassed :(